# assetic:dump from composer strange environment issue

Tags: git, symfony, compass-sass, assetic

I have composer setup to run assetic:dump :

```
"scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod",
            "php app/console cache:clear --env=prod"
        ],
```

When I SSH into my server and run `composer install`, it works great with no issues.  However, when I run `composer install` from a git post-update hook, I get strange errors about ruby not being able to find compass.  Ruby and compass are both installed correctly and it works fine when I run `composer install` "manually".

Is there some environment issue that I am running into?

edit:

The actual error message is:

```
...../rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs`: Could not find 'compass' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Comment: Is the error message "Could not find a valid gem ‘compass (>= 0) in any repository."? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes that is the error and no I am not behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  The git deploy script was running with an environment that did not contain the `GEM_PATH` environment variable.  By adding this line before running `assetic:dump` in the git hook script, everything worked:

```
export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
```